# Multiple command within one bash.sh

Tags: shell-script, systemd

I have put a few commands inside one .sh file. Separated by lines. More specifically it is `rclone`.

It is a program that mount cloud drives. The way it works without the `--daemon` option is it will echo a new line with a "blinking" cursor, outputting some info at times.

Sorry but I do not know the technical name for this.

I believe this is preventing the bash file from executing the second line of command, because the first one is still "unfinished" in amateur terms.

What is a way for all command to be run despite this property? I cannot use the `--daemon` option since the systemd which I plan to use to autostart the file does not like it and always return failed even with type `simple`.

Sample file:

```
#!/bin/bash

rclone mount drive: location

rclone mount drive2: location2
```

Comment: What version of **rclone** are you using? I ran into the same problem; backed down to v1.50 and the --daemon option worked.

Comment: @ajgringo619 do you mean it worked with systemd? What kill option did you use?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. It still needs a minor workaround. What I do is mount the drive without the --daemon switch, then kill it with CTRL-C. Then I can use the --daemon switch in a script and it works. Why - I have no idea.

Comment: Can't you just detach the mount commands in the script? rclone mount drive: location &